form of the verb before のを/のが and ことを/ことが
I'm wondering if I need to put the past tense verb in the first part of the sentence before "のを" if the last verb is already in the past?

昨日話してたのを聞いた /  昨日話してるのを聞いた -
I heard you were talking yesterday

Everything seems clear with ことを

彼が殺されたことを知った I found out that he was murdered
彼が殺されることを知った I found out that he is going to be killed (someone is going to kill him)

In the case of "こと" there is a big difference- in which tense the verb stand before こと. So, what about  のを/のが

Hey, this related post about the difference between の and こと might be useful: What is the difference between the nominalizers こと and の?

Firstly, “〜のを聞いた” doesn't mean what you seem to think it means. “昨日話してるのを聞いた。” doesn't mean “I heard you were talking yesterday.” but “I heard you talking yesterday.” It implies one observed the action for oneself, rather than hearing it from someone else, for which “と聞いた” or “ことを聞いた” would be used. We can also use “ところを聞いた” for directly observing the action; this works the same with all verbs of perception as far as I know.
Secondly, tenses in Japanese, unlike in English, are relative to the clause they're embedded in. In English, they are relative to the moment of speaking. Only the main unembedded ultimate matrix clause in Japanese has a tense relative to the moment of speaking. Because of this “〜たのを聞く” itself isn't very common because it would mean hearing something that happened in the past relative to the hearing. Same with any other verb of perception.
“たことを聞く” however is fairly common. One can say “話してたことを聞く” to mean “I hear that he was talking.”, we can put this in the past tense to mean “I heard that he talked.” but for this the talking itself has to take place before hearing of it because again, tenses in Japanese are relative, not absolute. We can also say “話すことを聞いた。” this means “I heard he was going to talk.” note how in English we use “was going”, as in, the embedded clause itself is the past tense, but we use “going” to indicate that it still happened in the future relative to the main clause as “I heard that he will talk.” implies it will happen relative to the now. Japanese doesn't specify this difference. The event one heard of could happen in the future relative to speaking, or not, all it specifies is that it will happen in the future relative to when one heard of it.
There are other cases where Japanese specifies more, for instance “きれいだったと思った。” for “I thought he was pretty.”. English does not specify whether the being pretty happened past relative to the thinking, or not. He might have stopped being pretty when one had that thought. In Japanese it always means that being pretty was in the past relative to that thought. “綺麗だと思った。” also means “I thought he was pretty.” but now he always was pretty at the time of thinking.

彼が殺されることを知った I found out that he is going to be killed (someone is going to kill him)

For this reason, this sentence can also mean “I found out he was going to get killed.” implying he was already killed when the conversation happened. All this implies that the planned killing occurs after the moment the speaker learns of it, whether this is before, or after the point the speaker utters this sentence is not specified.

So, if i would say 彼が殺されたことを知った I found out that he was murdered
彼が殺されることを知った I found out that he is going to be killed (someone is going to kill him), is this still written correctly, a good translation? From what I understand from your answer, it is correct, i think.

@saenai yes, that is entirely correct.
